# the user is not allowed to see the application as per developer set configuration in Korea?

Tags: xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

the user is not allowed to see the application as per developer set configuration. We get this error when our UNITY 3D application for iPhone opens facebook page in safari to log in via facebook.

It is working fine in United States and India but it gives error in Korea.

Can someone please help me on the same?

Thanks
Kushank

Answer (score 0):

Because of rating issue, Facebook stopped to service game page in KOREA
It's ok to login through Facebook SDK, but can't show game page on Facebook. If it's not your case, then i don't know too...